# Google Map API - update lat/long info

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am working on site updates for a company that includes adding a new Google Map for a new location.

I need to update the below code with new Longitude and Latitude co-ordinates, but don't know how to generate them based on the address.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    function gmap_load() {

    function createMarker(point, html, labeltext) {
     var marker = new GMarker(point, {title:labeltext});
     GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
       marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
     });
     return marker;
    }

      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("googlemap"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(51.71,-1.96), 11);
        map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GScaleControl());

        var point = new GLatLng(51.71448,-1.97357);
        marker = createMarker(point, 
        "<div class=smalltext>David Lloyd,<br>Latham Road,<br>Blunsdon,<br>Swindon.<br>SN25 4DL</ div>", "Swindon clinic");
        map.addOverlay(marker);

      }
    }

    //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: Looks like some of your code was clipped when creating this question. You'll need to fix it for us to be able to help you.

Comment: sorry John - thanks for letting me know. I have now fixed that issue above. The address I want to now show is stated at the end there in the div. Thanks

Comment: This is API v2. Retagged the question.

Comment: *"How do I work out the long/lat to replace in the code"* - I don't understand the question. What is your problem?

Comment: The code above shows an old maps co-ordinates. I have only updated the address at bottom. I need to get the right GLatLng numbers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found this site that provides you with the data I needed: http://universimmedia.pagesperso-orange.fr/geo/loc.htm

Thanks